# How can I call a function when the user clicks a button?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

Let's say I create a user control with a button for a silverlight navigation app. I want to use this user contol on several pages.  Each of the pages has a function called

```
void changecolor()
{
 //process request
}
```

When the user clicks the button I want it to call the `changecolor()` function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an event at the UserControl that the page subscribes on. When the event is fired the method is triggered.

```
UserControl1.ButtonClicked += (se, ea) => changecolor();
```